# Show items in ListBox through property MaxNumberOfVisibleItems in ViewModel?

Tags: wpf

I use MVVM pattern. In ViewModel has property `MaxVisibleItems`.
In View:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0 0 0 5"
     VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True">
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

how to calculating number of visible items in ListBox through `MaxVisibleItems` in ViewModel. That mean if there are 10 Items and MaxVisibleItems is 8, only 8 items are displayed and there is a scroll bar to scroll to the other items. That means, MaxVisibleItems sets the maximum height of the control which shows the items.
Thanks for help me !!!

Comment: Are the items in your ListBox of a fixed height?

Comment: @BIjington, thanks for your reply, Yes, they are. The items in my ListBox of a fixed height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you know the fixed height of your items then you can use the following:

```
public class FixedHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // Change to whatever your fixed height is.
    const int ItemHeight = 25;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Note that this currently will display the ListBox with a height of 0 when there are no entries. It would probably be sensible to make use of the MinHeight property in xaml or factor in a MinHeight property in this code.
        if (value is int)
        {
            return ((int)value) * ItemHeight;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            return ((int)value) / ItemHeight;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

And your ListBox needs to change to:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0 0 0 5"
         Height="{Binding MaxVisibleItems, Converter={StaticResource FixedHeightConverter}}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Note if you want to reuse this in other parts of your UI and you have different fixed heights then you could look at making the ItemHeight a property rather than a const.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty crazy solution:

Create an interface and a new class that inherits from `ObservableCollection`, this will allow us to work out how many items we should display using a **Converter**.

```
public interface ILimitedCollection : IList
{
    int MaxViewable { get; set; }
}

public class LimitedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ILimitedCollection
{
    private int _MaxViewable;

    public int MaxViewable
    {
        get { return _MaxViewable; }
        set 
        { 
            _MaxViewable = value; 

            OnPropertyChanged(new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("MaxViewable"));
        }
    }
}
```

Your collections should inherit `LimitedObservableCollection`, instead of `ObservableCollection`, and you can then use the following converter:

```
public class LimitedListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ILimitedCollection collection = (ILimitedCollection)value;

        ObservableCollection<object> items = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.MaxViewable; i++)
        {
            var item = collection[i];

            items.Add(item);
        }

        return items;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This will simply limit the number of items to display in the collection.

Usage:

```
{Binding YourCollection, Converter={StaticResource LimitedListConverter}}
```

**Notes**

You may be wondering why I didn't just make use of the `ConverterParameter`. Well, I could have, but it is not possible to bind the ConverterParameter to a property in your ViewModel. Hence, a more complicated solution had to suffice.

This may not be the *best* solution, however, it's certainly a start.

Answer (score 0):

Since your items have a fixed height, I suggest you to extend the `ListBox` control in this way:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ListBox : System.Windows.Controls.ListBox
    {
        public ListBox()
        {
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded);
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MaxVisibleItemsCount < Int32.MaxValue)
            {
                MaxHeight = (ActualHeight / Items.Count) * MaxVisibleItemsCount;
            }
        }

        public int MaxVisibleItemsCount
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MaxVisibleItemsCountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MaxVisibleItemsCountProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxVisibleItemsCountProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MaxVisibleItemsCount", typeof(int), typeof(ItemsControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(Int32.MaxValue));
    }
}
```

Then your XAML will be:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources />

    <DockPanel>
        <local:ListBox Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                       MaxVisibleItemsCount="5"
                       VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                       VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
            <local:ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </local:ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <local:ListBox.Items>
                <sys:String>One</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Four</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Five</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Six</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Seven</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Eight</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Nine</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Ten</sys:String>
            </local:ListBox.Items>
        </local:ListBox>

        <Grid />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I used a `Grid` to fill the remaining space. Without this `Grid`, the ListBox would expand its height in order to fill the available space in the window.